# Python under windows?

Tags: python, windows

Couple of questions about Python under Windows:

1. `shebang:`
   I thought i read somewhere that the `shebang` is supposed to work correctly under Windows but it doesn't for me. So

   `#!/usr/bin/env python`

   `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

   ```
   import sys

   sys.version
   ```

No matter what `shebang` I use above I always get 2.7.6 on a system where both 2.7.6 and 3.3.3 are installed

2.Unfortunately Python 3.3 is not named `python3.ex`e like on linux/mac. I want to have the ability to use both versions. I have my path variable set to 2.7.6 version first because thats what I'll probably use the most which means if I just type python thats the version. Is there any way to better manage this rather than having to type the full path to the executable or maybe dynamically changing the path variable?

Comment: Of course that it won't work, do you have /usr/bin/evn on your windows  box? I guess not! I don't know what you are tryint to achieve, but it may be that all you need is a python IDE like Pycharm.

Comment: Python 3.3 added the "py.exe" file to deal with shebangs and many other initialization things. You should use it to run your programs

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't usually a `/usr/bin` directory on Windows systems, even if shebang lines worked that wouldn't. You would instead need something like `#!C:\Python33\bin\python.exe`.

As far as I know, however, the shebang line is a Unix kernel feature that isn't available on Windows. I'd be happy to be wrong.

You would do well to look at using [virtual environments](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) - that allows you to set up the correct interpreter for each project, and keep the dependencies for different projects separate.